# How do I watch for onChange of specific select menu that was dynamically generated?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, v-select

I have a row of 3 inputs. It lay out like this:

> Attribute (select) > Operators (select)  > Value (text)

UI look like this:

[image]

Code for that:

```
<v-row v-for="(rule, index) in rules" :key="index">
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
        <v-select
            dense
            outlined
            item-text="name"
            item-value="id"
            label="Attribute"
            v-model="form.values.attributes"
            :items="attributes"
        ></v-select>
    </v-col>

    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="2">
        <v-select
            outlined
            dense
            item-text="name"
            item-value="id"
            label="Operator"
            v-model="rule.operator"
            :items="operators"
        ></v-select>
    </v-col>

    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
        <v-text-field
            dense
            outlined
            label="Values"
            v-model="rule.value"
        ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

The operator menu is dynamically populated based on API based on the selected attribute.

I have `v-model="form.values.attributes"`, and my watch to call the API for the operators

```
watch: {
    'form.values.attributes'() {
        let data = {
            $root: 'rules'
        }
        axios.defaults.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        axios.post(window.MTS_URL, data).then((response) => {
            this.operators = response.data.operators
        })
    }
}
```

This works great with one row.

But when I clicked Add, I appended another row, and I need to support multiple rows.

[image]

**How do I watch for onChange of specific select menu ?**

---

I was thinking to move my

```
v-model="form.values.attributes"
```

to

```
v-model="rule.attribute"
```

but is it the right thing to do ?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

You can try remodeling your data to experience the power of Vue.

Your template:

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <v-row v-for="(rule, index) in rules" :key="index">
            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
                <v-select
                    dense
                    outlined
                    item-text="name"
                    item-value="id"
                    label="Attribute"
                    :items="rule.attributes"
                    @change="onChange($event, rule, index)"
                ></v-select>
            </v-col>

            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="2">
                <v-select
                    outlined
                    dense
                    item-text="name"
                    item-value="id"
                    label="Operator"
                    :items="rule.operators"
                ></v-select>
            </v-col>

            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                <v-text-field dense outlined label="Values"></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

Notice how everything is rendered in the `rules` data. Here the rules data will be an array containing all the rows:

```
rules = [
    { 
        attributes: ["11", "22"],
        operators: []
    }
]
```

Your script should look like below:

```
<script>
import axios from "axios"

export default {
    name: "App",
    data() {
      return {
        rules: [{
           attributes: ["11", "22", "33"],
           operators: [],
        }],
      };
    },
    methods: {
        async onChange(changed, rule, index) {
            // where:
            // `changed` is the value selected
            // `rule` is the attributes and rule in the selected row
            // `index` is the index in the rules array that just got changed
            console.log(changed, rule, index);
            const operators = await this.fetchApiData(changed);

            this.$set(this.rules, index, { ...rule, operators: operators });
        },
    },
    async fetchApiData(data) {
        const response = await axios.post(window.MTS_URL, data);
        return response.data.operators;
    },
};
</script>
```

if you want to add more rows, you just need to push an object to the `rules` data:

```
this.rules.push({
    attributes: ["new attribute 1", "new attribute 2"],
    operators: []
})
```